# What is the lore/back story associated with various legendaries and set items

Tags: diablo-iii

There are a ton of sets and legendary items in Diablo III. Several of them are inspired from other game/story universes or some event in them. I found out about a few through the battle.net forums or Game Guide comments, examples:

- ***Guardian's Regalia***: reference to Magneto from X-Men
- ***Wondrous Deflectors***: Wonder Woman reference
- ***The Burning Axe of Sankis***: refers to a specific incident in a game of Dwarf Fortress

What are the various references in such items? I am interested in a full list, with more details on the lesser known ones (e.g. Axe of Sankis)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad, Alok, because as you said there are a ton of sets and legendary items, and a good answer would essentially be a wiki page describing all of them, which is not something the Q&A format is good at. I think questions about specific items would probably be okay, though.

Comment: @Sterno Sounds good, I think its a smaller list than I expected - but it seems to be still too broad, and hasn't even got a single quality answer (I also didn't follow up and research it myself :/ )